# Android WebView bug with zoom

Tags: android, webview

WebView does not seem to work properly after zoom (performed with touch). 
To reproduce after page load zoom page but do not allow view to be scrolled after zoom (it will cause the issue not to appear). Click on link. Link highlighted like it is clicked but WebView not navigate to the next page (so visually it remains on same url).
Here are test project [source](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2263037/temp/TestWebViewBug.tar.gz)  and [apk](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2263037/temp/TestWebViewBug.apk) to reproduce this.

Reproduced on Nexus S and  HTC wildfire S.
I'll appreciate any thoughts or directions.

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class TestWebViewBugActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        });
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");

    }
}
```

P.S.
Layout XML in sources and apk changed according to suggestions from comments (height is now static value)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to fix your Main.xml file. The layout height in your WebView is "fill_parent". When the client zooms inn the WebView enlarges impacting the parent. This is your Main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Try giving the WebView a defined height. Then try zooming inn and see what happens.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="500px"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

In layout main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <WebView 
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In activity

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
```

And It should work.
Instead of google.com try other pages. On my phone opens default browser. But my private page works fine :)

Comment: Thanks for checking this. Default browser opened because you removed

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {});

In default browser there is no such problem. Only in webview. Also playing with layout_xxxx did not help.

Comment: THx for the hint. Its working properly right now.
One more thing, for what api ver app did you made? I created my for 8 (2.2) and it works fine on my Galaxy S with 2.3.4. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: It was set to 4 (1.6). Switching to 2.3 did not help. This is not quite easy reproducible thing unless you know how to reproduce it (main thing is to not allow view to move after it was zoomed) so maybe you just did not reproduce it.